# При обновлении таблицы игнорировать значения NULL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица вида `id | p1 | p2 | p3`, где `id` - первичный ключ.

Обновляю сразу несколько строк запросом:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (id, p1, p2, p3)
VALUES 
    (1, 0.1,  0.2,  0.3), 
    (2, 0.1,  NULL, 0.3), 
    (3, NULL, 0.2,  0.3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    p1=VALUES(`p1`), p2=VALUES(`p2`), p3=VALUES(`p3`)
```

Вопрос: как изменить запрос, чтобы значения `NULL` игнорировались, и в БД оставались старые значения? Как-то типа `p1=VALUES(p1) IF NOT NULL`, не могу сообразить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать функцию [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

```
INSERT INTO `table` (id, p1, p2, p3)
VALUES 
    (1, 0.1,  0.2,  0.3), 
    (2, 0.1,  NULL, 0.3), 
    (3, NULL, 0.2,  0.3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    p1=IFNULL(VALUES(`p1`), p1), p2=IFNULL(VALUES(`p2`), p2), p3=IFNULL(VALUES(`p3`), p3)
```

Данная функция возвращает первый аргумент, если он не NULL, в противном случае возвращает второй аргумент.